# Can I use SELECTION mode on FeatureLayer from ArcGIS.com Webmap in ESRI JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, popup, feature-service

I am using an `ArcGIS.com Webmap` in an ESRI Javascript API application I am developing.  One of the layers in my `Webmap` is rather large and cannot be rendered all at once when zoomed out, however I would like to avoid showing holes in the data on screen when data does actually exist there.

I have seen samples and demos before where it is possible to use a tiled map service to cover the entire large area without rendering all the individual features, but still be able to show an `InfoWindow` when the map is clicked.  I am assuming this would be done using a `FeatureLayer` with its `mode` set to `SELECTION` and the `onClick` handler for the `map` would query the `FeatureLayer` based on where the `map` was clicked, then the selected features would appear on the `map` and the `InfoWindow` could be visible.

I have not seen where it is possible to set the `mode` of a `FeatureLayer` that is provided via an `ArcGIS.com Webmap`.  If I simply create a new `FeatureLayer` in my application that points to the `Hosted Feature Service` on `ArcGIS.com`, then I lose all of the configuration (symbology, popup, etc.) that I have done when publishing the `Webmap`.

Is what I have described above possible?  If not, is there another way to render a large number of features on the map and still have access to attribute information?

Comment: I am not sure regarding first part of your question but yes if you want to display large number of features with an attribute information. You can try mouse hover option please check following link ( I have tried and its working fine for me) http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/query_hoverinfowindow.html

Comment: @Sunil - this is similar to what I am trying to accomplish however this example uses a regular `FeatureLayer` and not a `FeatureLayer` provided by an `ArcGIS.com Webmap`.  The `Webmap` doesn't seem to provide all the options that a `FeatureLayer` constructor does.

Answer (score 1):

The webmap returns a featureLayer already instantiated. I haven't tried changing the mode to instantiate a featureLayer with mode selection, but it makes sense that you lose symbology and popups because you set those when instantiating.

Solution: I have queried (queryTask) against the featureLayer url based on user drawn polygon (or user click, hover, etc), and then set the features (polygons) returned from the query to an outline of aqua blue, and then added them to the graphic layer -- so it looks like they are selected.

Meanwhile, I'm displaying the featureLayer from the web map underneath that shows the symbology, popups, etc that were configured in the webmap. Of course, you could achieve the same effect with a tile cache and you wouldn't be limited by the 1000 record max limit -- that may be better for you. I turned the visible scale to only show close in for the webmap.

Here's a sample -- (adapted and untested)

```
//goes inside your your onclick function here
if (geom !== null) {
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query(),
        queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(params.parcelServiceName); //featureLayer url
    query.geometry = geom;
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    query.outFields = ["*"];
    queryTask.execute(query, function (results) {
        highlightPolygons(results);
    }, function (error) {
        //vgis.app.jQueryUIAlert(vgis.config.APP_STRINGS.ERROR_CONDITION);
    });
}
else {
    //vgis.app.jQueryUIAlert(vgis.config.CUSTOM_STRINGS.PARCEL_NO_RESULTS);
}

//function to add aqua highlighting outline
function highlightPolygons(results) {
    var geom,
        graphic,
        symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0, 255, 255, 1.0]), 2),
            new dojo.Color([255, 255, 25, 0.0]));
    map.graphics.clear();
    dojo.forEach(results.features, function (key, value) {
        geom = value.geometry;
        graphic = new esri.Graphic(geom, symbol);
        map.add(graphic);
    });
}
```